# Mockito testing framework not working in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am starting to write unit tests for my application and have problem with `Mockito` functionality in Android Studio. For example I can't mock `Context` object. Here is my very basic code:

**ExampleUnitTest.java** class:

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Mock Context context;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(context.getString(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn("Test");
    }
}
```

In my app level **build.gradle** file I have such dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

So according to all tutorials, etc. everything should be OK. But when I try to run my test, I get such exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class: ExampleUnitTest
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.gapps.trailplanner.ExampleUnitTest.test(ExampleUnitTest.java:20)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.

    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.Reporter.formatUnncessaryStubbingException(Reporter.java:838)
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.UnnecessaryStubbingsReporter.validateUnusedStubs(UnnecessaryStubbingsReporter.java:30)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:45)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:104)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What I am doing wrong here that I can't mock simple `Context` object `getString()` method functionality?

Comment: The top six lines of your exception trace seem to be pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you're not actually using the mock.

> Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class: ExampleUnitTest
>
> Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

These Unnecessary stubs are stubbed method calls that are never realized during test execution.
You can write:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
       context.getString(any(Integer.class))
    }
```

Same can be avoided using `Silent` option like

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {
```

}

Developer adds up unnecessary test code. In order to keep the codebase clean it is necessary to remove unnecessary code.